# ZK Teco Finger Print PHP

Tags: php, biometrics, zkteco

I tried to get the attendance data using [tad-php](https://github.com/cobisja/tad-php) library but I got an error
error to connect, tried following all tutorial and troubleshot i found on the git or google but still cannot connect. My device using ZEM600 firmware.

Any one has experience like this?

here my code to call:

```
<?php
require 'tad/lib/TADFactory.php';
require 'tad/lib/TAD.php';
require 'tad/lib/TADResponse.php';
require 'tad/lib/Providers/TADSoap.php';
require 'tad/lib/Providers/TADZKLib.php';
require 'tad/lib/Exceptions/ConnectionError.php';
require 'tad/lib/Exceptions/FilterArgumentError.php';
require 'tad/lib/Exceptions/UnrecognizedArgument.php';
require 'tad/lib/Exceptions/UnrecognizedCommand.php';


 $tad_factory = new TADPHP\TADFactory();

 use TADPHP\TADFactory;
 use TADPHP\TAD;



 $comands = TAD::commands_available();

 $b1 = (new TADFactory(['ip'=>'myipaddress']))->get_instance();

 $dt = $b1->get_date(); // method executed via TAD class.
echo $dt;
```

socket and curl mod enabled.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the error msg? What is your device model?

Comment: Hi @Roldan, It siad cannot connect to device, using the X401 Machine

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all relevant information, like the error message and your attempts to resolve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

1. Ping the device IP with your computer to make sure the device does ping?
2. Go to the main menu to your device then select the COM option and then go to the PC Connection option and see the Com-Key value and make sure its value is zero.
3. If your device is using the ZEM600 or less Firmware then I'm sure it will work.